# Mejorando las habilidades de revisión: Determinar las razones para reabrir o mantener cerrada una pregunta

Tags: discusión, revisiones

> ### TL;DR
>
> ¿Qué opción elegir al votar una reapertura cuando el OP al editar su pregunta, elimina la causa de cierre original, pero cae en otra? *Plus*, ¿cómo ayudar al OP a que obtenga las respuestas que necesita?

Buenas noches.

He tenido algunos problemas a la hora de decidir si una pregunta editada debe ser reabierta o debe permanecer cerrada. Quisiera exponer el caso más reciente con el que me he enfrentado y busco argumentos que me ayuden a tomar una mejor decisión sobre la orientación de mi voto: *mantener cerrada* o *reabrir*.

Inicialmente el OP hace esta pregunta: [Edición 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/24557/1), una hora después hace una ligera edición, [Edición 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/24557/2). En este punto la pregunta ya está cerrada, con la bandera *"no está claro lo que se pregunta"*.

El OP reacciona ante los votos de cierre y edita la pregunta, [Edición 3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/24557/3).

Esta es la situación que me causa conflicto:

> El OP agrega, en mi opinión, suficientes elementos para aclarar el motivo de su pregunta: describe su situación actual y el resultado esperado. Sin embargo, me parece que la pregunta ahora cae en la clasificación de *"demasiado amplia"*.

#### De las opciones ofrecidas en la revisión de reapertura, ¿qué opción ayuda más al usuario y/o la comunidad, *reabrir*, visto que aclaró su pregunta o *dejar cerrada*, dado que ahora me parece que es demasiado amplia?

Las preguntas que caen en esta categoría son muy complicadas de resolver para mi, el ejemplo es puntual, pero expone un caso que me ha tocado frecuentemente, tan es así que tengo muy pocos puntos en esa medalla, porque la mayoría de las veces me abstengo de votar.

Comment: Al evaluar la reapertura, hay que evaluar **todos** los posibles motivos de cierre. Si pensabas que era "demasiado amplia", la opción a elegir era "Mantener cerrada"... Quería aclarar que voté para reabrirla porque me parecía una pregunta que podía ser contestada así como estaba luego de la edición.

Answer (score 1):

Como muy bien dices la última edición mejoró sustancialmente la pregunta pero a la vez aún falta un poco más para ser 100% aceptable en el sitio dentro de las normas que hemos definido como comunidad.

En estos casos lo mejor es [dejar un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24557/graficar-un-arbol-binario-a-traves-de-una-matriz#comment39928_24557) para ayudar al usuario a corregir la problemática.

Si se es amable y empático con los usuarios nuevos normalmente entienden cuál es el problema con la pregunta y lo editan para solucionarlo. Tened en cuenta que estos usuarios tienen poco conocimiento de cómo va el sitio y qué es aceptable o no y con pequeñas cosas como un comentario se les puede ayudar mucho.

Asimismo, si el usuario no tiene la medalla de [Informado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed) es recomendable proponerle que visite el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) que es importante para los nuevos usuarios de la comunidad.

Comment: Además, en estos casos, se ve que el usuario ya está editando la publicación, por lo que dejar un comentario para ayudarle sería muy útil. Tratemos de mantener a los usuarios informados de cómo pueden resolver estos temas. Inclusive, recomendaría que se les comente a los usuarios que revisen esta publicación de meta: [¿Puedo usar meta para preguntar detalles sobre mi pregunta antes de publicarla en SOes?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/637/227) aunque en este caso sería para corregirla una vez publicada, que también es válido.