# Cierre por demasiado amplio incorrecto: Meter una lista en una lista doblemente enlazada (Matriz) - C++

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta, motivos-de-cierre

La pregunta [Meter una lista en una lista doblemente enlazada (Matriz) - C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56718/meter-una-lista-en-una-lista-doblemente-enlazada-matriz-c) está cerrada por demadiado amplia. Que según el centro de ayuda significa :

> Muy amplia - si tu pregunta puede ser respondida por un libro entero,
>   o tiene muchas respuestas válidas, probablemente es muy extensa para
>   nuestro formato.
>
> > Existen muchas respuestas posibles o buenas respuestas pueden ser muy
> >     extensas para este formato. Por favor. Por favor agrega detalles para
> >     reducir el conjunto de respuestas o para isolar un problema que puede
> >     ser respondido en pocos párrafos.

No es el caso de esa pregunta. Implementar una matriz dispersa en C++ con listas dobles son unas 50-100 líneas en C++ incluso sin usar la STL. Y la mayoría es boilerplate code.
Es algo que se puede abordar en una respuesta de SO. Por lo que invito a reabrir la pregunta.

Harina de otro costal es si la pregunta es una buena pregunta.
Está claro que es un ejercicio académico. Y el trabajo de investigación que muestra es muy reducido. Puedo entender que se vote negativo o que se pongan comentarios pidiendo una mejor redacción.

Pero cerrarla por demasiado amplia manda el mensaje incorrecto. Le estamos diciendo al usuario que no puede preguntar sobre matrices dispersas en general; que es algo sobre lo que sí se puede preguntar. Y no le estamos diciendo que debe mejorar su pregunta.

Escribirle la solución en 100 líneas de código no es una buena idea. Yo tampoco quiero promover los usuarios que solo quieren que les hagan las tareas. Pero si queremos **buenos usuarios** también debemos ser **buenos moderadores** (y no me refiero a los diamantados, me refiero a todos nosotros al votar o cerrar). Si a un usuario le exigimos que haga unas buenas preguntas a nosotros debemos exigirnos hacer una buena moderación, lo cual incluye cerrar por el motivo correcto.

Comment: Relacionada: [Mejorando las habilidades de revisión: Determinar las razones para reabrir o mantener cerrada una pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/896/mejorando-las-habilidades-de-revisi%C3%B3n-determinar-las-razones-para-reabrir-o-man)

Comment: La pregunta a la que se refiere este hilo ha sido eliminada. Sólo los miembros con [Acceso A Herramientas De Moderación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (rep >= 2k) puden verlo.

Comment: Jose, ¿Planeas responder a esa pregunta, cierto?

Comment: No creo lo vaya a responder. De hecho si ven la respuesta primeramente la considero demasiado amplia eferion que en verdad es un experto en C++. Mi opinión es que en verdad la pregunta es demasiada amplia.

Comment: @fredyfx Sí, aunque antes tendría que editarla para que alcance un estandar mínimo de calidad.

Comment: en ese caso, ya está el voto a reapertura, espero que la respondas con toda la calidad del caso como mencionas :D

Answer (score 4):

Sin abordar el porque del cierre (que IMHO me parece correcto), la pregunta en si es mala. Escribe 6 lineas de definicion de punteros, no explica que hizo o no hizo, no declara cual es su problema particular, y si queres copiar las 100 lineas de codigo y terminarle el ejercicio esta en vos, pero me parece que como se viene discutiendo ultimamente no aporta nada (ni al sitio ni a ningun lado, en google ya debe haber 6000 ejemplos).

Esto no es una libreria de documentacion, eso se esta intentando en SO eng.

Volviendo al tema del motivo del cierre, que es por lo que preguntas, no se que otro motivo darle. No tenemos un motivo falta de esfuerzo para preguntar. Tal vez seria bueno agregarlo?

Saludos.

Comment: Sin querer juzgar esta pregunta en particular, porque no soy experto en la materia... en general, me parece que "falta de esfuerzo" no es en sí una razón válida para cerrar una pregunta. Ciertamente es una razón para votar en contra, y para abstenerse de contestar si uno no desea promover esa clase de preguntas. Pero creo que hay que tener cuidado de no convertir nuestro disgusto personal por una pregunta en un voto de cierre que en realidad no es aplicable.  Pero estoy de acuerdo que si la comunidad desea cerrar las preguntas por falta de esfuerzo, tendría que agregarse una razón para eso.

Comment: Cuando una pregunta no cumple con las "expectativas" de calidad, el motivo de cierre más apropiado sería "no está claro lo que se pregunta", sin embargo, la descripción de este motivo es "demasiado amplio" por lo que sería muy bueno que se incluya un comentario específico con las recomendaciones para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: gbianchi, ¿estás seguro de que en google hay 6000 ejemplos de como hacer una matriz dispersa con listas doblemente enlazadas en C++ en ESPAÑOL?

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos ok, tienes un punto en la parte que aclaras en español. Igual como referencia es un mal ejemplo escribirle a alguien 100 lineas de codigo, van a terminar todos viniendo a buscar eso mismo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo en que escribirle la solución en 100 líneas de código no es una buena idea. Yo tampoco quiero promover los usuarios que solo quieren que les hagan las tareas. Pero si queremos buenos usuarios también debemos ser buenos moderadores (y no me refiero a los diamantados, me refiero a todos nosotros al votar o cerrar). Si a un usuario le exigimos que haga unas buenas preguntas a nosotros debemos exigirnos hacer una buena moderación, lo cual incluye cerrar por el motivo correcto.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Estamos totalmente de acuerdo en ese punto.

Comment: @gbianchi Estoy de acuerdo contigo.