# ¿Hasta que punto el ser estrictos beneficia a la comunidad?

Tags: discusión, motivos-de-cierre, moderación, usuarios-nuevos

El tema que me gustaría tratar es sobre la aparición de los nuevos usuarios y la duración que tienen estos en la comunidad. Si que es cierto que se tratan temas sobre como actuar con las preguntas pero no he visto algo sobre esto.

Al tema que quiero llegar es el trato que se les da los nuevos usuarios. Si bien es cierto que hay muchos usuarios que realmente solo quieren que se les ahorre trabajo para hacer un copia y pega, también hay muchos que realmente quieren aprender,entender y crecer  con la comunidad y me atrevería a decir que un porcentaje exagerado de esos usuarios no duran mas de 2 días en la comunidad.

Para un usuario nuevo la pagina nos es para nada lo que pretende ser, al principio es cierto que no conoces todo y no cumples al 100% de las reglas pero la respuesta es horrible.

 Este tema lo he tratado con varias personas que les encanto la pagina al principio y al de unos días no querían ni mirarla y a día de hoy ni siquiera entrar.

- Publicas una pregunta > viene alguien y te la cierra, fin del tema > Porque ? ni idea? no cumple con alguna norma, búscate la vida.
- Publicas una pregunta > viene alguien te corrige las tildes > horas después otro usuario cambia las listas ordenadas por las no ordenadas > viene otro usuario cambia el tipo de links > días después entra otro y cambia el espacio del final de 3 filas  a 1, que 3 es demasiado > Conclusión? > 6 personas se han corregido entre si tu pregunta y de ellas nadie responde(aun sabiendo sobre el tema) , pero ehh!!, la gramática esta que reluce.
- Publicas pregunta (perfectamente estructurada, con una opinion-duda al final) > Viene alguien, negativo, Copy/Paste del comentario por defecto "Bienvenido a la comunidad...Lee como formular bien una pregunta en ..." > Y la pregunta?? > Búscate la vida, pero ehh al menos esta vez cumple las normas.
- Pregunta publicada hace días con cientos de visualizaciones y obviamente ediciones, 0 respuestas! > Le contestas lo mejor que puedes > Milagro la pregunta la ven decenas de personas, pero ehh que raro, entran a editar tu respuesta y sino, pues  porque no, ya que lo tengo en el porta papeles  == "Bienvenido a la comunidad... Lee esto sobre como responde..."

Y sucesivamente en muchos,muchos casos cuando el usuario es nuevo mas que ayudar a que se integre se le acribilla. Entiendo que las cosas tienen que seguir reglas  y estructura para funcionar de manera mas eficaz pero... Al final se le acaba dando mas énfasis a que quede todo bien bonito que al hecho de responder o ayudar al usuario. 

Esto lleva pasando mucho y supongo que seguirá pero los pocos días que llevo respondiendo preguntas he visto estos casos y mas de usuarios que parece que es a lo único que se dedican a corregir a los nuevos usuarios y listo, que se busquen la vida con la pregunta.

Creo que se debería reconsiderar sobre este tema ya que solo espanta a los novatos y creo que es bastante fácil de identificar quien realmente quiere aprender y quien solo quiere ahorra trabajo, lo suficiente al menos actuar de manera diferente.

---

**UPDATE**

Entiendo las explicaciones puestas y concuerdo con ello, todas estas reglas hacen que el sitio funcione de una forma mucho mas rapida y dinamica. Pero mientras que para un usuario de SO estas reglas sean normales, para alguien que acaba de entrar por primerza vez a SO el formato es algo totalmente nuevo,y aunque las acciones realizadas solo ayudan a mejorar dicha pregunta/respuestas el hecho que la gente empiece a modificar tu propia pregunta/respuesta o votarlo de forma negativa porque no cumple el formato impacta bastante ya que no estas acostumbrado a ello. Ya he visto sugerencias de denegar a los usuarios hacer preguntas hasta conseguir cierta medalla, no creo que esto sea muy efectivo, pero una restriccion inicial para eviar que los nuevos usuarios pasen por esto y que los mods tengan que estar cerrando preguntas que no cumplen las normas no vendria nada mal y de hecho seria hasta mas efectivo.

Comment: En tu pregunta veo dos cosas bastante distinas. Principalmente el tema de ser estrictos, pero veo que comentas sobre la falta de respuestas (punto 2 y 4). Si bien la corrección de la pregunta es importante para la cabida de la misma, no implica que por ello vaya a tener respuestas. De eso dependen factores como la tecnologia, el grado de detalle, e incluso en qué franja horaria fue publicada... En tu punto 3, tienes algun ejemplo de preguntas bien formuladas que hayan tenido ese tipo de comentarios *predefinidos*? Quizá el comentario fue previo a la edición de la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: El tema al que intento llegar es que cuando un usuario es nuevo, la impresión que se lleva uno es que importa muchísimo mas la estructura y la gramática de una pregunta/respuesta que el fin de que esta sea útil. Si una alguna pregunta/respuesta no cumple lo establecido en muchos casos se cierra al momento, no se da nada de tiempo de meditar, cambiar,aprender simplemente= esta mal. Siguiente. Y parece que todo lo demás no importa es decir si es útil para la gente? Da igual,demasiado texto =cerrado. Da igual, tienes 1 linea de 20 que es una opinión,= cerrado.

Comment: Bueno, para ser *estrictos* no se **cierra**, si no que se pone **en espera**. Son estados similares. No hay que pensar en esos estados como en algo malo. Significa que la pregunta tal y como está no correcta.  Hay preguntas basadas en opiniones que si no se cierran , se llenan de comentarios publicados como respuesta dando sugerncias de aplicaciones, por ejemplo. O preguntas muy simples que les falta mostrar qué problema tienen, se llena de respuestas identicas o similares que en mi opinion no ayudan mucho al usuario mas que en hacerle la busqueda que no hizo. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) El cierre de la pregunta da posibilidad a que se mejore y a su vez evita futuros problemas con las respuestas. Hay casos de preguntas muy pobres o nada claras que responden con un comentario del estilo "me pasó algo parecido y con tal herramienta se solucionó" y se marca como aceptada e incluso tiene votos positivos. Con un cierre se pone una pausa al proceso de pregunta/respuesta hasta que la pregunta está lista. Un saludo

Comment: A eso es a lo que voy.  El problema es que la gente aplica estas normas al pie de la letra sin excepción alguna, la frase que has publicado  "me pasó algo parecido y con tal herramienta se solucionó" por desgracia del autor de esta, dependiendo de quien ha sido el primero y con mayor autoridad, puede que exista o puede que ya no. por mucho que ayude o no ,es una experciencia/opinion", no cumple, resultado =dependiendo del mod, se borra o no, cuando realmente ayuda a muchos, da igual

Comment: No entendí del todo tu ultimo comentario, pero no se borra. En todo caso, se convierte en comentario bajo la pregunta. Yo entiendo que si la respuesta es esa (y sin posibilidad de mejora o más info) es que la pregunta no es válida.

Comment: Acaba de aparecer esta pregunta (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185764/brackets-no-previsualiza-mis-archivos-ni-muestra-emmet?noredirect=1) y parece que al autor le sentó bien la puesta en espera y los comentarios. ¿Es el tipo de preguntas a las que te refieres? ¿Habrías hecho algo distinto? Un saludo

Comment: @CristianS9 Siempre hay este tipo de discusiones en SOes y SOen, y yendo a tu post, no pienso que el problema sean las ediciones(existen casos extraños en que el usuario se molesta porque toma a mal que se corrijas su pregunta). El problema que veo es que muy pocas preguntas tienen respuestas, y el motivo de ello dependen de la formulación de la pregunta por parte del usuario y de la comunidad. De parte del usuario es por una mala formulación de su pregunta principalmente, o de la comunidad porque quizas no hay expertos en todos los temas.

Comment: [cont] Por otro lado para responder no se califica a la persona, puede ser principiante o un experto, la respuesta o no respuesta debe ser indiferente a ello ya que SO es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas de calidad, ese es el elemento distintivo de SO respecto a otros foros.

Comment: [cont] A lo mucho que se hace es que los usuarios interesados en responder realicen las preguntas y él que ha creado la pregunta se tome el tiempo de responderlo y actualizar su respuesta, Recuerda que para obtener algo el esfuerzo es necesario y si el nuevo usuario esta interesado en aprender lo hará.

Comment: @CristianS9 ¿estas pidiendo que los nuevos tengan como privilegio no ser modificados?, si es asi no te parece contradictorio, al que más ayuda necesita prohibes ayudarle, ademas ¿estas pidiendo que no haya votos en contra?, ningun usuario puede tener menos 1 en reputación para no tener el disguste de tener -inf de reputación, los votos son otorgados de la comunidad para calificar la calidad una pregunta o respuesta, y si es mala es como una crítica, y tanto como en SO y la vida real debemos ser capaces de recibir las criticas. ¿No crees que quieres sobreprotegerlos?

Comment: Toda persona que usa un servicio (cualquiera) debe atenerse a sus reglas. Internet (y este sitio en particular) tiene sus reglas. Nadie puede decir que hizo algo porque no sabia, y menos si ni siquiera leyo el recorrido, cosa que a los nuevos usuarios se le recomienda cuando empiezan en el sitio.

Comment: @eyllanesc En ningun momento he dicho algo asi

Comment: @CristianS9 okay, quiza lo entendí incorrectamente, por favor explicame que significa: *pero una restriccion inicial para eviar que los nuevos usuarios pasen por esto*, ¿que acción en concreto buscas?

Comment: @eyllanesc Me refiero a que veria mucho mas practico el evitar que un usuario recien registrado pueda hacer una pregunta a dejarle hacerla mal y que le lluevan los negativos

Comment: @CristianS9 vayamos al caso contrario, si el usuario nuevo es capaz de realizar una pregunta interesante y formularla correctamente ¿le deberiamos prohibir hacerlo?¿crees que seria justo?

Comment: Prohibirle a un usuario preguntar, invalidaria a montones de usuarios que necesitan preguntar antes de poder dar una solucion. Por eso hay iniciativas para que los usuarios primerizos puedan preguntar mejor. Y estas dejando de lado algo importante. La idea del sitio es que futuros usuarios encuentren la pregunta y la respuesta, por lo tanto, las dos deben ser claras.

Comment: Realmente lo mas cierto y real que vi, hay algunos superusuarios (con mas puntaje) que prefieren corregir todo menos dar la respuesta, hasta te dan puntuacion negativa, con esas motivaciones con razon veo tantas preguntas con muchas visualizaciones y menos respuestas muy buen hilo @CristianS9

Comment: no se si es tarde, pero igual tu estas haciendo algo no ha marcado una respuesta como aceptada , y si ninguna es aceptada no vi un comentario tuyo de el porque no fue aceptada , para los que se demoran en generar una buena respuesta esperan un feedback y aveces no se tiene aunque la respuesta sea buena

Comment: @JackNavaRow No habia puesto una exactamente porque se que no va a durar mucho como la respuesta acertada, porque aunque para mi es la que mas se acerca al tema `general` al que intento llegar para el resto es un respuesta mala tal como se puede ver con los votos.

Comment: @CristianS9 es la idea de StackOverFlow gracias al sistema de puntos el usuario no la borraria (otras de las maravillas del sitio) el usuario recibe 2 puntos negativo por cada pregunta no acertada pero 15 por pregunta valida, en esta oportunidad se oberva mucho por que son opiniones y por este motivo se evitan en SoEs y es una conducta que muchos usuarios evitamos aveces podemos estar equivocados pero para eso 4 personas deben estar de acuerdo Bienvenido a la Comunidad puedes estar en el [chat] y aprender/enseñar mas

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Cuando sopla la brisa la caña rígida domina imperiosa el campo
>   mientras la flexible se doblega ante su majestuosidad.
>   Cuando sopla el huracán la caña rígida se rompe y la flexible
>   sobrevive.

El ser así de estricto no va a ser bueno. Pero ya no tiene remedio. Acepta el sitio como es o busca otro.

Los estrictos han ganado la partida en Stack Overflow en español. La forma tan estricta y elitista como se maneja este sitio no es parte de las reglas del sitio, de hecho SO en general lo quieren dirigir a ser más receptivo y "nice" a los usuarios, los nuevos y las minorías en particular. Hay sitios, como el japonés, en que no te cierran una pregunta por haberla puesto en inglés. SOes podría haber sido de otra manera. Pero la manera de ser de SOes la decide una minoría que está dispuesta a dedicar una gran cantidad de tiempo al sitio y a meta. El tiempo es oro y aquí es más cierto que nunca. Con su esfuerzo y dedicación los estrictos se han ganado el derecho a que el sitio sea como es. Y a que evolucione como acabará evolucionando.

Y esto no afecta solo a novatos que no se han leído las normas del foro. También afecta a usuarios veteranos que no están incumpliendo las normas del foro, sino que se usa el cierre de preguntas para restringir el ámbito de SOes y hacer la comunidad menos inclusiva. Por ejemplo:

- [Consultar y leer datos MySQL mediante PDO de forma segura y eficiente [cerrada]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81028/consultar-y-leer-datos-mysql-mediante-pdo-de-forma-segura-y-eficiente)

Por supuesto los estrictos lo son solo con los demás, nunca consigo mismos. Veamos :

- [Cierre por demasiado amplio incorrecto: Meter una lista en una lista doblemente enlazada (Matriz) - C++](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1629/cierre-por-demasiado-amplio-incorrecto-meter-una-lista-en-una-lista-doblemente). Donde se reconoce lo incorrecto del motivo de cierre. Pero como la pregunta es mala pues... bueno... pues así se queda mal cerrada. Tampoco hay que ser estricto cuando no interesa, ¿verdad?

Y además están las preguntas en que podríamos aceptar que estuviese bien cerrarla, no estoy de acuerdo pero lo comprendo, pero se han manejado de forma abusiva :

- [¿ Es posible saber cuando rotas el móvil en Unity? [cerrada]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65300/es-posible-saber-cuando-rotas-el-m%C3%B3vil-en-unity) Además de cerrada está bloqueada "mientras se resuelven las disputas sobre el contenido de esta" desde hace **más de un año**. Esto es un evidente abuso del privilegio de bloqueo.

Y un ejemplo más reciente que sí afecta a un novato:

- [¿Cómo se denomina el par de corchetes en cada uso diferente? [en espera]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185771/c%C3%B3mo-se-denomina-el-par-de-corchetes-en-cada-uso-diferente). La respuesta se encuetra en la [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf). La cual no he encontrado en español. Buen sitio sería SOes para cubrir ese hueco. Incluso aunque la JLS estuviese en español la pregunta sería buena puesto que es un documento bastante difícil de digerir.

El ser así de estricto no va a ser bueno. Pero ya no tiene remedio. Acepta el sitio como es o busca otro.

Comment: Una consulta, ¿cuando de esos casos conoces?, sería importante saberlo, me preocupa, en especial  el segundo caso.

Comment: @eyllanesc Debe haber muchos casos, pero yo solo he tratado algunos. Otro ejemplo es [Contar repeticiones de enteros C++, Array (cerrada y borrada)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43823/contar-repeticiones-de-enteros-c-array/43831#43831) cerrada por "no está claro lo que se pregunta", cuando está claro clarísimo lo que se pregunta. Se [discutió en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1471/vamos-a-negar-la-posibilidad-de-preguntar-al-que-no-sabe-nada)

Comment: El problema de que se esta cerrando incorrectamente una pregunta es un problema muy particular, en SOen hay un sistema de evaluación para lo que se considera moderación por parte de los usuarios que no somo moderadores, pienso que eso deberia implementarse en SOes para minimizar esos problemas, yo pienso que los moderadores diamantados deberian reabrir esa pregunta, y pedir que el motivo de cierre sea el correcto. A mi me huele que los que votaron para cerrar esa pregunta lo hiciero sin leerlo, y justamente el sistema de evaluación evita ello en SOen.

Comment: Yo no pienso que ser estricto sea lo malo, ser estricto no significa ser torpe, porque para mi es una torpeza cerrar una pregunta señalando un motivo claramente diferente. ser estricto no significa ser abusivo. Pienso que deberias buscar otra palabra en vez de estricto.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81216/discussion-on-answer-by-jose-antonio-dura-olmos-hasta-que-punto-el-ser-estricto).

Answer (score 7):

Para dar una especie de respuesta, vamos a analizar lo que decis punto por punto:

- **Cierre rapido**: Esto es muy raro que ocurra, salvo que la pregunta sea fraglantemente en contra de las reglas del sitio. Desgraciadamente para algunos, el sitio tiene reglas. No es que rechaza novatos ni entusiastas, es solo que se pide cierta clase de investigacion previa a hacer una pregunta. Si alguien pregunta algo que facilmente se encuentra en google, es muy probable que la mayoria de los usuarios vean la pregunta y salgan corriendo. A veces contestarlas lleva mas trabajo que la busqueda esa, y como no queda bien decirle ve a fijarte en google o lee el manual, entonces directamente es muy probable que nadie le haga caso. Sin embargo, es raro que un cierre sea rapido. Los moderadores suelen esperar a que alguien mas vote por el cierre, y los usuarios que podemos cerrar preguntas no somos tantos como para cerrarlas rapidamente.
- **varias personas ven la pregunta y no la contestan**: y alguien puede asegurar que sepan la respuesta? yo edito preguntas para corregir el formato, por ejemplo muchisimas de lenguajes que desconozco totalmente, para que si entra alguien que sepa no tenga que tomarse el trabajo. Sin embargo, eso no quiere decir que se pueda contestar. Si escribes un query enorme y no me dices el explain plan, el describe de las tablas, un set de datos, probablemente solo pueda arreglarte la pregunta y te pida toda esa informacion que falta.
- **El mensaje predefinido**: yo lo pego siempre que el usuario haga una pregunta que no cumple los estándares, no haya leído el recorrido, su pregunta tiene menos datos de los necesarios. Eso no quiere decir que yo sepa la respuesta. Si es de android seguro que no se la respuesta. si es de js seguro que tampoco la se. Y sin embargo, tratamos de facilitar el trabajo de alguien que por ahí si la sepa. La comunidad todavía esta creciendo, y ayudar a hacerla crecer es que tenga valor en todo sentido. Que un usuario sepa que tiene que aceptar una respuesta por ejemplo es una forma de hacer que la comunidad crezca. Y el comentario por defecto no es negativo. y si te parece negativo, con gusto te invito a que lo critiques para que podamos hacerlo menos negativo. cada usuario tiene su propio mensaje, la idea es enseñar a los nuevos usuarios a usar el sitio, no espantarlos.
- **Mensajes en respuestas**: Eso es mas raro. Usualmente se deja un mensaje solo si la respuesta es de muy baja calidad, y solo si el usuario ni siquiera leyo el recorrido. Igual siempre se agradece por la respuesta.

Estaria bueno tener ejemplos concretos de lo que decis, cada uno tiene su punto de vista respecto a como tiene que funcionar el sitio, y el tema de los nuevos usuarios fue tratado incontables veces. Sin embargo, que un usuario sea nuevo no quiere decir que puede hacer lo que quiera o preguntar lo que quiera. Hay dos o tres links relativamente cortos para leer (como el recorrido) que le indican a grandes rasgos que hacer. No se critica a un usuario que hizo una buena pregunta solo porque esta mal formateada, pero asi como uno tiene respeto por el tiempo del otro en la vida real, se pide un minimo de respeto tambien aca.
Hacer una pregunta y ni siquiera preocuparse por dar un set minimo de datos o poner que se intento o se averiguo, es lo mismo que ir por la calle preguntando aleatoriamente cosas a la gente, a ver si alguien sabe. Aca tenes gente que sabe mucho, pero para poder responder y no tener que escribir un libro, necesita que sean claros quienes preguntan.

Fijate que en tu caso, contestaste montones de preguntas, no entre en todas, pero te aceptaron pocas. Esto puede ser porque quien pregunto no tenia idea como funcionaba el sitio y no acepta respuestas (cosa que pasa muchisimo), o directamente abandono su pregunta (cosa que tambien pasa montones de veces). Esto es lo mismo que hacer perder el tiempo a alguien, y por eso se pide cierto grado de responsabilidad. Te tomaste el tiempo para responder, pero quien te pregunto, no se tomo tu tiempo en serio, ni otorgandote puntos, ni dandote un feedback, ni haciendo nada al respecto. (todo esto que digo, no es personal, es general, ya que no analice ni una de las pregutnas que respondiste).

> Los usuarios nuevos con ganas de aprender y de participar, se atañen a
>   las reglas, mejoran sus preguntas y se transforman en buenos usuarios
>   del sitio, empezando a responder tambien. Los usuarios que solo vienen
>   a que les escriban su codigo, pasan sin pena ni gloria, como pasan por
>   otro monton de sitios.
>
> Tratar de ayudar a los nuevos con todas esas cosas que vos ves como
>   negativas, aunque no lo creas sirve para filtrar los unos de los
>   otros.

Comment: _Los usuarios nuevos con ganas de aprender y de participar, se atañen a las reglas, mejoran sus preguntas y se transforman en buenos usuarios del sitio, empezando a responder tambien_ → ¡gran explicación! Lo comparto totalmente.

Answer (score 4):

Como diría Jack, vamos por partes:

> Publicas una pregunta > viene alguien y te la cierra, fin del tema > Porque ? ni idea? no cumple con alguna norma, búscate la vida.

Si una pregunta se cierra **siempre** se indica el motivo: ¿*Duplicada*? hasta te aparece el enlace de la pregunta que estás duplicando, creo que es bastante útil. ¿*No relacionada* porque no has puesto el código que te falla? Edítala y añade lo que se te pide, no te podemos ayudar en otro caso.

> Publicas una pregunta > viene alguien te corrige las tildes > horas después otro usuario cambia las listas ordenadas por las no ordenadas > viene otro usuario cambia el tipo de links > días después entra otro y cambia el espacio del final de 3 filas a 1, que 3 es demasiado > Conclusión? > 6 personas se han corregido entre si tu pregunta y de ellas nadie responde(aun sabiendo sobre el tema) , pero ehh!!, la gramática esta que reluce.

Muchos usuarios estamos contínuamente mirando la lista de preguntas recientes. Si yo veo una pregunta con una errata procuro corregirla, pero si la pregunta es de una tecnología que no conozco obviamente no podré ayudar al autor con una respuesta. Al editarla ayudo a:

- Que sea más legible, por lo que será más atractiva a un potencial lector que sepa la respuesta.
- Que aparezca en la lista de preguntas activas: una edición hace que una pregunta *se mueva*, con lo que es más accesible a potenciales lectores.
- A que la pregunta sea votada positivamente: una pregunta bien hecha y con cierto cuidado con el lenguaje (somos desarrolladores, los lenguajes de programación son muy estrictos!) dará más reputación al usuario.

En resumen, no hay motivos para quejarse porque hayan editado tu pregunta/respuesta a menos que el resultado empeore (lo que es raro porque hay revisiones).

> Publicas pregunta (perfectamente estructurada, con una opinion-duda al final) > Viene alguien, negativo, Copy/Paste del comentario por defecto "Bienvenido a la comunidad...Lee como formular bien una pregunta en ..." > Y la pregunta?? > Búscate la vida, pero ehh al menos esta vez cumple las normas.

Como he comentado, los que nos leemos la pregunta/respuesta no siempre sabemos del tema, pero nos gusta que el contenido del sitio tenga cierta calidad. Si un usuario nuevo no tiene ni una medalla significa que no ha leído el texto de bienvenida que aparece al registrarte (te dan una medalla por ello). Si la pregunta/respuesta es de mala calidad o no encaja con lo que se espera en este sitio, lo decimos.

Cada uno tiene sus costumbres, yo no votaré negativo una respuesta a menos que sea claramente incorrecta o induzca al que pregunta a usar malas prácticas o hacer algo mal. En cualquier caso se suele dar un motivo en un comentario (a veces el comentario es de alguien que **no** ha votado negativo pero conoce la dinámica del sitio).

> Pregunta publicada hace días con cientos de visualizaciones y obviamente ediciones, 0 respuestas! > Le contestas lo mejor que puedes > Milagro la pregunta la ven decenas de personas, pero ehh que raro, entran a editar tu respuesta y sino, pues porque no, ya que lo tengo en el porta papeles == "Bienvenido a la comunidad... Lee esto sobre como responde..."

¿Tiene cientos de visualizaciones? Está atrayendo la atención, eso es bueno. ¿No tiene respuesta? Quizá no tiene todos los detalles para que entendamos el problema o realmente nadie de los que la ha visto ha sabido responderla. Quizá haya algún comentario pidiendo más detalles para reproducir el problema. O quizá es un problema tan raro o de una tecnología tan específica que nadie sabe la respuesta.

Entiendo que un usuario se pueda sentir agobiado al entrar, es difícil medir las consecuencias de una acción individual cuando somos tantos:

Si preguntas a un compañero de trabajo una duda de una forma que no deje claro qué pasa, te pedirá explicaciones sobre la marcha. Entrarás en una dinámica de depurar el problema [depurando tu propio entendimiento del mismo con lo que muchas veces lo resolverás sin ayuda](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_depuraci%C3%B3n_del_patito_de_goma)

Si preguntas aquí de la misma manera, 10 personas que no se pueden levantar e ir a tu PC a ver tu código te pedirán explicaciones o se quejarán de que faltan detalles. Y entiendo que 10 comentarios ligeramente negativos en unos minutos puedan parecer una avalancha de quejas, pero realmente tienes que verlo como que **esas personas están usando su tiempo para tratar de ayudarte**. Sé paciente y esas personas también lo serán.

En resumen: ser estrictos es distinto a ser ariscos. Intentamos lo primero y a veces podemos dar una impresión equivocada, pero aquí estamos para intentar ayudar.

Comment: Yo uso al agente P (Perry).. (regalo de un niño) :p.. no consegui un patito de goma :p

Answer (score 2):

Cristian, en el caso de StackOverflow en español te podría asegurar que la comunidad no es "estricta" en realidad, a diferencia de otras comunidades, siendo nuevo usuario puedes realizar una publicación que no cumpla con lo que dicta el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) y te aseguro no terminara inundada de votos negativos o cerrada casí al instante.

En el caso de StackOverflow en español se brinda a los nuevos usuarios la oportunidad de mejorar su publicación, incluso las preguntas permanecen abiertas y la comunidad realiza sugerencias para mejorar.

Ahora bien, existen muy pocos usuarios que aún sugiriéndoles revisar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) no lo consideran importante y mucho menos el [¿Cómo elaborar una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) o [¿Cómo escribir una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Regularmente todos [**deseamos se nos brinde la información rápidamente**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/186218/crear-una-pagina-adicional-en-angular), pero es importante realizar nuestra publicación adecuadamente.

Considera estos puntos:

> 1) Las preguntas no se cierran al instante, siempre tenemos un poco de
>   paciencia para que el OP modifique su publicación. Existen casos en
>   los que se han realizado publicaciones no adecuadas en el sitio y
>   procedemos a eliminar la publicación.
>
> 2) Las preguntas se pueden poner en espera pero en realidad se pueden
>   volver a reabrir si estas cumplen lo definido en el [Centro de
>   ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)
>
> 3) Si el usuario realiza continuamente publicaciones no adecuadas
>   probablemente seriamos un poco más estrictos, incluso se puede enviar
>   un mensaje de aviso por parte de los moderadores.

---

Personalmente te quiero comentar que los [moderadores elegidos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), no obtenemos compensación monetaria, medallas o puntos de reputación por agregar comentarios, sugerir mejoras a preguntas/respuestas, ayudar en las colas de revisión, incluso es importante tener algo de paciencia ya que sabemos que continuamente entraran al sitio usuarios que desconocen de su funcionamiento.

Todo lo realizamos por convicción, porque deseamos un sitio donde los usuarios encuentren información valiosa que ayude a resolver sus dudas o problemas.

Son importantes estos comentarios,

gbianchi (Gonzalo Bianchi):

> [Los usuarios nuevos con ganas de aprender y de participar, se atañen
>   a las reglas, mejoran sus preguntas y se transforman en buenos
>   usuarios del sitio, empezando a responder también.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3595/95)

muchos de estos usuarios recuerdo al inicio no veían como importante lo definido en el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) pero ahora incluso además de realizar excelentes contribuciones al sitio nos ayudan continuamente a moderar el sitio con sus reportes y ayuda a nuevos usuarios!

Pablo Lozano:

> [tienes que verlo como que esas personas están usando su tiempo para
>   tratar de ayudarte.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3596/95)

Generalmente la comunidad trata de ayudar a que mejores tu pregunta y puede dar comentarios para que realices una buena publicación y esta pueda ser bien recibida en la comunidad y principalmente obtengas la ayuda que requieres.

Te puedo asegurar que hay que ser muy pacientes para ver todos los días nuevos usuarios y agregar un mensaje para que realicen al menos el recorrido del sitio, pero al final he visto que la recompensa es que tenemos usuarios que aportan al sitio preguntas y respuestas de calidad y además ayudan enormemente a la moderación para tener un sitio con información valiosa de programación, desarrollo y uso de software.

> Para vivir en una comunidad es necesario tener reglas que moderen el
>   comportamiento y nos ayuden a tener un lugar donde vivir cordialmente
>   y disfrutar de sus beneficios, en este caso del conocimiento y la
>   ayuda de todos.