# ¿Se debe reabrir una pregunta para cerrarla por otro motivo más correcto?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

La pregunta es sobre:

[¿Por qué al hacer el ejercicio Tour of Heroes me da el error "Cannot find name 'HEROES'"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/72117/2027)

¿Aquí qué pasa? La pregunta fue cerrada por estar en inglés, después se respondió, pero parece que el problema es un error tipográfico que también es motivo de cierre.

¿Qué se debería hacer en estos casos?

¿Votar por la reapertura? y después esperando que se reabra, ¿votar para cerrar por el verdadero motivo?

Es decir, de alguna forma está mal que esté cerrada por el motivo actual (en este caso que estaba en inglés).

¿O se debería poner un reporte para que moderador lo revise?

*<sub>La pregunta ya alcanzo 4 votos para reabrir</sub>

*La votación esta 5 vs 4, aún está cerrada para mi

Comment: No creo que valga la pena abrir simplemente para cambiar el motivo de cierre, ya que eventualmente podría ser eliminada la pregunta por Roomba o por el propio autor de la pregunta. Me parece que con que se deje un comentario al respecto es suficiente. Por otro lado, me gustaría conocer la opinión de los moderadores diamantados acerca de si conviene hacer este tipo de reportes.

Comment: Creo que la clave está en los comentarios. En este caso, tanto la preguntadora como el contestador atendieron los comentarios de manera muy amable. Hay una [pregunta relacionada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/896) y también apuntan a los comentarios.

Comment: Al revisar la pregunta la consideraría de baja calidad y que no aporta mucho al sitio, por tal motivo, **dejarla cerrada**. No es la primera vez que veo una pregunta cerrada por un mal criterio (al momento de realizar las revisiones), lo único que hacía era añadir un comentario y explicar al OP que no considere el motivo de cierre, sino el otro.

Comment: El motivo de cierre ya es el de _error tipográfico_. ArtEze lo hizo hace dos días. Véanse las [revisiones de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/72117/revisions) con toda la información.

Comment: @fedorqui Si lo vi, pero voto por dejarla cerrada aqui en la discución, de hecho le puse un comentario

Comment: Ah vale, ahora entiendo: te referías a que en esta pregunta la respuesta de lois6b tiene 5 votos a favor y la de ArtEze 4. Pensé que te referías a la pregunta, perdona.

Comment: @fedorqui no hay problema

Answer (score 4):

<sub>En [estos comentarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092/ser-paciente-con-los-votos-cuando-una-pregunta-est%c3%a1-en-ingl%c3%a9s/1102#comment2711_1102) en Meta 
hablé sobre este tema de abrir para volver a cerrar.</sub>

Yo creo que si se cerró por estar en inglés, y se ha traducido, se ha de reabrir **incluso aunque vaya a cerrarse por otro motivo** porque el usuario **no sabe** qué tiene mal.

Hasta ahora sólo se le ha comentado que la traduzca (aunque a veces también se le añade que aún traducida le falta explicación u otras cosas).

Una vez en español, ya se le puede explicar su otro problema con consecuencias de cierre. Si no se le explica, ¿cómo va a cambiar y mejorar su pregunta?

---

El tema de cierre ahora es más peliagudo por los pocos usuarios que pueden votar y lleva más tiempo que una pregunta sea cerrada, pero sí, si el cierre original se ha resuelto ha de abrirse. Y si un nuevo motivo se ve presentado en la pregunta, volver a votar.

Comment: Bien visto. Al fin y al cabo, el motivo de cierre pretende ser una guía para que el usuario sepa qué ha hecho mal y pueda corregirlo.

Comment: ¿Con _Esto ya se comentó alguna vez pero no encuentro la pregunta en Meta_ tal vez te refieres a [Cerrado por demasiado amplio usado para preguntas de baja calidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1833/83)?

Comment: No, @fedorqui. Edité mi respuesta con el enlace hehe

Answer (score 1):

#### Dejarla cerrada.

El motivo no importa mucho, hay veces que yo elijo un motivo, pero por mayoría, al final aparece otro motivo.

Comment: En la versión en inglés recién voté para cerrar [una pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44088145/1595451) y aparecieron dos motivos, cada uno con dos votos. Aún no veo un caso así por acá.

Comment: @Rubén actualmente sucede exclusivamente cuando se está votando por cerrar como "no relacionado" y hay múltiples motivos, pero no sucede a posteriori cuando ya fue cerrado (lo que no recuerdo es si era sólo en SO o en toda la red)

Comment: @Mariano: Gracias por compartir la observación. Así pasa en el caso que mencioné en mi comentario previo, se votaron dos distintos "sub-tipos" de pregunta no relacionada.

Comment: como ya he explicado en mi respuesta no me parece bien que se quede cerrada por ese motivo. ahora el usuario la tiene en español y sigue cerrada por estar en ingles :/

Comment: Comentas aquí que seria mejor dejarla cerrada, pero votaste por reabrir la pregunta.

Comment: @jasilva Tenés razón, no tuve en cuenta un tercer motivo de cierre, ahora que está claro lo que se pregunta, solo era un error tipográfico. Ahora la dejé cerrada.